# how to redirect express.js request directly to 404

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I would like to send a request to a certain route within express.js directly to 404 if the user is not authenticated.

in my middleware I have the following code:

```
exports.isAuthenticated = function (req, res, next) {
  if (req.isAuthenticated()) {
    next();
  } else {
    res.redirect("/login");
  }
};
```

what I would like to do instead is to present the user with a 404 page instead. I have configured one globally, but I dont know how I am supposed to skip every chained middleware for a request and send a user to 404 directly.

Thanks for answers :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

okay I got the answer. I have to use

> If you need to skip the rest of the middleware from a router
>   middleware stack, call next('route') to pass on the control to the
>   next route. Note: next('route') will work only in middleware loaded
>   using app.VERB() or router.VERB().

according to http://expressjs.com/guide/using-middleware.html and its working